# Does RethinkDb support request pipelining?

Tags: rethinkdb

Does RethinkDb support request pipelining, grouping multiple requests in one connection? If yes, is it done automatically behind the scenes in a lower level?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RethinkDB currently does not process more than one query per connection at a time.

In the special case of insert operations, batched inserts can be used to obtain a similar effect.

Edit: This answer is outdated. Since RethinkDB 2.0, multiple queries can be executed on the same connection at the same time, as long as the driver supports issuing multiple queries without waiting for the previous one to finish.

Comment: This could be interesting to be implemented to improve network performance. Actually this could be a bottleneck, because all intracluster and client connections are TCP and proxied to each master node of a shard for each request. So, if we have an application with a big volume of  up-to-date reads and writes we can easily saturate a cluster.

Comment: Intracluster communication is pipelined. Just not client connections.